# Convert a numpy array to a structured array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures, dtype

Given that the width in bytes for rows in numpy array and the sum width of fields in a structure defined by dtype are the same, is there a simple way to convert such numpy array to a structured array?

For example, `my_type` defines a data type with 5 bytes per data element in all fields: `[('checksum','u2'), ('word', 'B', (3,))]`. Then I want to convert the numpy array `[[ 1  2  3  4  5] [ 11 12 13 14 15]]` to the structured array `[( 258, [ 3,  4,  5]) (2828, [13, 14, 15])]`.

My initial attemp was this:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

# generate data
array = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5), 
    (11,12,13,14,15)], dtype = np.uint8)

# format data
my_type = np.dtype([('checksum','u2'), ('word', 'B', (3,))])
structured_array = np.array([array], dtype=my_type)
```

But, as expected, because of [numpy broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#assigning-data-to-a-structured-array), I get the following:

```
[[[( 1, [ 1,  1,  1]) ( 2, [ 2,  2,  2]) ( 3, [ 3,  3,  3])
   ( 4, [ 4,  4,  4]) ( 5, [ 5,  5,  5])]
  [( 11, [ 11,  11,  11]) (12, [12, 12, 12]) (13, [13, 13, 13])
   (14, [14, 14, 14]) (15, [15, 15, 15])]]]
```

My current not-so-elegant solution is to loop through the rows of an array and map them to the structure:

```
structured_array = np.zeros(array.shape[0], dtype=my_type)
for idx, row in enumerate(array):
    for key, value in my_type.fields.items():
        b = row[value[1]:value[1]+value[0].itemsize]
        if len(structured_array[idx][key].shape):
            structured_array[idx][key] = b            
        else:
            structured_array[idx][key] = int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big', signed=False)
```

So the question is whether there is a simple, one-line solution to perform this task for an arbitrary data type of a structured array, without parsing bytes of a numpy array?

Comment: the data for a structured array has to be a list of tuples, same layout as in the display.  Each tuple is a `record` or element of the structured array.

Comment: `np.array([(1,[2,3,4])],my_type)`, The nesting of () and [] is important.

Comment: `recfunctions` has a `unsteuctured_2_structured` function, but I'm note sure it can handle your dtype.  That inner (3,) field makes conversion trickier.

Comment: Another way is to create a `zeros` array with the desired shape and dtype, and assign values by field.

Comment: All I wrote should be covered on the main structured array doc page.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed, it souldn't be a problem to convert a "structured" data to a structured array or parse data field by field. However, I want to do it with plain binary data and with an arbitrary dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [222]: x = np.array([[ 0,  2,  3,  4,  5], [ 0, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [223]: dt = np.dtype([('checksum','u2'), ('word', 'B', (3,))])
```

I know from past use, the `genfromtxt` can handle relatively complex dtypes:

```
In [224]: np.savetxt('temp', x[:,1:], fmt='%d')
In [225]: cat temp
2 3 4 5
12 13 14 15
In [226]: data = np.genfromtxt('temp', dtype=dt)
In [227]: data
Out[227]: 
array([( 2, [ 3,  4,  5]), (12, [13, 14, 15])],
      dtype=[('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
```

But I haven't dug into its code to see how it maps the flat row data on to the dtypes.

But it turns out the `unstructured_to_structured` that I mentioned in a comment can handle your dtype:

```
In [228]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [229]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(x[:,1:],dtype=dt)
Out[229]: 
array([( 2, [ 3,  4,  5]), (12, [13, 14, 15])],
      dtype=[('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
```

But for simpler dtype, I and others have often recommended turning the list of lists into a list of tuples.

```
In [230]: [tuple(row) for row in x[:,1:]]
Out[230]: [(2, 3, 4, 5), (12, 13, 14, 15)]
```

Many of the `recfunctions` use a field-by-field copy

```
In [231]: res = np.zeros(2, dtype=dt)
In [232]: res
Out[232]: 
array([(0, [0, 0, 0]), (0, [0, 0, 0])],
      dtype=[('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
In [233]: res['checksum']= x[:,1]
In [234]: res['word']
Out[234]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
In [235]: res['word'] = x[:,2:]
In [236]: res
Out[236]: 
array([( 2, [ 3,  4,  5]), (12, [13, 14, 15])],
      dtype=[('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
```

### byte view

I missed the fact that you wanted to repack bytes.  My above answer treats the input line as 4 numbers/ints that will be assigned to the 4 slots in the compound dtype.  But with `uint8` input, and `u2` and `u1` slots, you want to `view` the 5 bytes with the new dtype, not make a new array.

```
In [332]: dt
Out[332]: dtype([('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
In [333]: arr = np.array([(1,2,3,4,5),
     ...:     (11,12,13,14,15)], dtype = np.uint8)
In [334]: arr.view(dt)
Out[334]: 
array([[( 513, [ 3,  4,  5])],
       [(3083, [13, 14, 15])]],
      dtype=[('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
```

`view` adds a dimension, that we need to remove:

```
In [335]: _.shape
Out[335]: (2, 1)
In [336]: arr.view(dt).reshape(2)
Out[336]: 
array([( 513, [ 3,  4,  5]), (3083, [13, 14, 15])],
      dtype=[('checksum', '<u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
```

and changing the endedness of the `u2` field:

```
In [337]: dt = np.dtype([('checksum','>u2'), ('word', 'B', (3,))])
In [338]: arr.view(dt).reshape(2)
Out[338]: 
array([( 258, [ 3,  4,  5]), (2828, [13, 14, 15])],
      dtype=[('checksum', '>u2'), ('word', 'u1', (3,))])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the full data range, i.e. `x[:,:]` instead of `x[:,1:]`.

Comment: For some reason I'm starting with a (2,5) int array `[222].`  I don't remember where I copied it from. To convert a (2,5) byte array, all you may need is a `view`

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? For example, afer changing to proper range at `224`: `np.savetxt('temp', x[:,:], fmt='%d')` the output is `[(0, [ 2,  3,  4]) (0, [12, 13, 14])]`, it misses the second byte of the first field `('checksum','u2')`. Also, I have changed the data in the question to better represent, where the problem with the suggested solutions may be.

Comment: I added a `view` based answer.

Comment: The `view` is what I was looking for. Thanks!